# Regarding addressing modes - where does an offset start?

Tags: architecture

So an addressing mode is the way that an operand is specified (from what I understand) and there are different modes provides by different architectures, such as Immediate mode, register indirect mode, etc.

In that context, I frequently encounter an a specification of an offset, such as in the direct mode where you specify the operand's offset directly in the instruction like `ADD AL,[0301]` - but an offset from what? There must be some base address or something that the offset is based on? Is there some starting place, like an address of an instruction ?

Comment: Addressing mode "foo" with an offset of x describes an address x bytes beyond the one described by plain addressing mode "foo" (without offset).

Comment: @KilianFoth and what could that address described by the plain addressing mode "foo" be? The address of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at disassembly of a running program i.e. from a debugger, then an absolute memory mode could be exactly that.  It your case it would be address 301 in the address space of the process being debugged.

---

However, in certain processors there is a CPU register that provides the base address for data accesses.

For example, the 8086 processor, which is an extended version of a 16-bit processor to allow access to a 20-bit address space.  The extension is screwy, in that they combine two 16-bit values to compute a 20-bit address (thus, 32-bits are used to produce a 20-bit address!).

The formula is 20-bit address = segment portion * 16 + offset portion.

In accessing data, for example, the processor maintains a register called `DS` to hold the base segement, and in instructions we specify the offset only, which will appear in form as if it were a direct/absolute addressing mode, though the processor will actually compute `DS:offset` (which is they way they write the formula to compute a 20-bit address from a segment register and an offset value).

Assembly code might look something like:

```
dataSeg segment data
...
xyz     db 5
...
```

then in code

```
mov ax, dataSeg           #1
mov ds, ax
...
mov al, offset [xyz]      #2
...
mov ax, offset xyz        #3
mov bl, [ax]              #4
```

Note that in #1 the `DS` regsiter is loaded with the data segment value declared in a segment directive (two instruction sequence, since DS is limited in instructions that use it).  The first intruction is using what we would call an immediate mode, since no actual memory is being access.

Next, in #2, we're asking the processor to load a byte into `AL` from `DS:offset xyz` where `DS` holds the segment address of the `dataSeg`.  The instruction only specifies `offset [xyz]`, and not the segment portion.  We would probably call this a direct/absolute addressing mode, as there is an immediate involved as part as a address computation for an interaction (here a byte read) with memory.  One could argue that this is an base+offset addressing mode, except that the base is an implicit register.

In #2, we're asking the processor to load the offset itself rather than doing a memory fetch; the offset is loaded into `AX`.  This would be an immediate addressing mode, since memory is not actually being accessed.

In #4 we use the offset loaded by #3, so the fetch of the byte from memory into `BL` comes from `DS:AX`.  We might call this simply indirect.  Again, one could argue that this is base+index, except the base is the implicit segment register.

---

Once the x86 family went to 32-bit registers, (e.g. 80386 and beyond) they did away with most of that segment/offset stuff.  So, direct/absolute addressing is more straightforward and values refer to addresses the address space.

However, there other processor do/have used a register dedicated for the load-time relocation of the data segment.

Comment: Wow thanks again! However, I have some questions: (1) you say that "certain processors there is a CPU register that provides the base address for data accesses." - will the base address provided in the register be an address in RAM and, in that case, could it be any address in RAM?

Comment: (2) "20-bit address = segment portion * 16 + offset portion" + #1-4 - is the segment portion/address the base address and would that be in RAM?

Comment: (3) "It your case it would be address 301 in the address space of the process being debugged." - because the base address is 0? Why is the base address 0? And like I kinda asked in the two questions above - is the base address/the place from which the offset is added always a place in RAM?

Comment: (3) most operating system offer a process notion of an address space, which ranges from 0 to as much memory as your currently have.  Though to be clear there can be holes in the address space.  There is no base: the address space starts at 0 and goes up from there thru all possible values -- though there may be no memory at all addresses (there may be holes in the memory blocks at some address ranges).

Comment: (1) "will the base address provided in the register be an address in RAM and, in that case, could it be any address in RAM?"  In theory, yes, but that would partially be up to (a) the what the processor supports and (b) how the operating system lays out the address space for a process as that will add some restrictions, and also (c) what the program itself is expecting (which may leave only one place for that data to live).

Comment: I added some description to the main text as to what addressing mode #1-#4 might correspond to.

Comment: So in all cases, the base address stored in the register will always be a location in RAM? Otherwise, how exactly could a "base" be stored from which you can add an offset? I am slowly starting to get it

Comment: and is a "base segment" an address?

Comment: Not sure if you were notified about my last two comments, so i'll just place one more comment and hoping that would help :) Maybe I am just too impatient though...

Comment: it is the base but it is not an address, just the 16-bit segment portion of the address.

Comment: And that is the numbers preceding the offset or?

Comment: Recall that the full 20-bit address = segment * 16 + offset.

Comment: Ohhh, so it is the 16-bit part of the whole address in RAM?

Comment: Yes, of the two 16-bit parts forming the 8086's 20-bit address, one is multiplied by 16 and the other is not.  That means the segment and offset have 12 overlapping bits.  It's screwy but that's what it is.  This means that segment can be made to refer to any memory address that is on 16 byte boundaries.  Once a segment resister is set, from there code can reach a block of memory up to 64k as the offset is 16-bits, without changing that segment register.

Comment: One programming model then, is to load the segment registers once and leave them alone for the duration of the program.  That means that for that program a pointer is really just the 16-bit offset, and that the program can not access more than 64k of data.  A different programming model is constantly changing the segment registers values, and stores 32-bits for pointers (it only needs to store 20 but that's actually harder to do).

Comment: Wow god bless you. You are the best. I actually understand how it works now.